# Effective way of using SQL statements in Protractor Tests

Tags: javascript, oracle, protractor, cucumber, ui-automation

I am writing a protractor test that tries to validate the UI against the DB values. I am first trying a simple test

This is how my step definition looks like:-

```
Given(/^I run a random select query$/, function(){   
    let sql2 = "Select * from table Where ID  = 8888";
       return this.db.getConnection(dbConfig).then(function(connection) {
                return connection.execute(sql2).then(function(result, err){
                    return console.log(result.rows.toString());
           });
          });

       });
```

The above test works fine

1) **this.db** refers to oracleDb import and it's part of my custom Constructor in world.js
2) DBconfigs are included as a file in my config.js

Could someone please advise as to how I can abstract the hardcoded sqls out of  the step def and make them separate so as to maintain them effectively;  call or generate them when I have to for a certain step. Basically, any example or idea of managing SQLs, db tables and connections to diff environments in a more effective manner

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but an approach,  probably need more one time efforts but it has worked out really well for me. if you can build a [RESTfull APIs around DB quires](https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/) and call the APIs whenever needed.